# Replace and increment tag value in XML file with sed

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I'm working in Linux and in my XML file I'd like to replace `<version>` tag value by another string, when the number value will be incremented by 1 one. For example if I have XML file like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rm.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>rm-dt-agr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>rm-dt-agr</name>
</project>
```

I'd like to replace `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` in tag `<version>` by `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT`
If it's `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT` value I'd like to replace it with  `0.0.3-SNAPSHOT`
and so on...

I tried to use "sed" command but without success.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those situation where you should really use a tool meant for processing XML rather than trying to shoehorn a bash solution. That being said, for simple tag substitutions with minimal format gymnastics involved, bash can work quite well.

For any situation where you are looking to change a line in a file, you will need to write the changes to a new or temp file and then copy to replace the original. (while theoretically, since you are only changing a single character and not adjusting the line-length, you really can just write the changes to the new file, but beware)

The difficulty here is you have a *5 character sting*, with *3 digits separated by* `'.'` (periods) instead of a simple number. No matter what tool you choose, you will have some string manipulation to do to parse down to the point where you know the value you need to increment. Then once found, you must preserve the format (meaning you must account for any time an increment causes your value to change from a *single-digit* number to a *two-digit* number) Presumably, you must adjust the value of the next digit if your increment causes the single digit to overflow.

There are a couple of approaches you can take. You can manually create a new file that reflects the changes by writing all lines, except the one that changes, to the new file without any modification. Of course, write the changed line as well. The second would be to parse the file to get the line that needs changing, do the calculation to increment the number and then use `sed` to do the substitution.

The following takes the manual approach and writes a complete new file. Look over it, give it a try, and remember -- you are better served finding an XML tool to parse and modify XML...

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z $1 ] && {  ## validate input file given
    printf "error: insufficient input. usage: %s filename\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

[ -r $1 ] || {  ## validate input file readable
    printf "error: file not found/readable\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

ifile="$1"      ## set input/output filename, truncate output file
ofile="${2:-newxml.xml}"
:> "$ofile"

while IFS= read -r line; do                     ## for each line
    text="${line// /}"                          ## remove leading spaces
    if [ "${text//>*/}" = '<version' ]; then    ## match version tag 
        nspcs=$((${#line} - ${#text}))          ## save # spaces removed
        value="${text#<version>}"               ## strip tags from ends
        value="${value%</version>}"
        nstr="${value%-*}"                      ## separate number string
        label="${value#*-}"                     ## from text -SNAPSHOT
        IFS=. read v1 v2 v3 <<<"$nstr"          ## read separate numbers
        [ -z $v1 -o -z $v2 -o -z $v3 ] && {     ## validate
            printf "error invalid value: '%s'\n" "$value"
            continue
        }
        v3=$((v3 + 1))          ## increment by 1
        [ $v3 -eq 10 ] && {     ## adjust remaining if 10
            v3=0
            v2=$((v2 + 1))
        }
        [ $v2 -eq 10 ] && {
            v2=0
            v1=$((v1 + 1))
        }                       ## output updated line to new file
        printf "%*s%s\n" $nspcs " " "<version>$v1.$v2.$v3-$label</version>" >> "$ofile"
    else
        printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$ofile"   ## write other lines unchanged
    fi
done <"$ifile"

exit 0
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/file.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rm.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>rm-dt-agr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>rm-dt-agr</name>
</project>
```

**Example Use**

```
$ bash xmlchgvalue.sh dat/file.xml dat/new.xml
```

**Output File**

```
$ cat dat/new.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rm.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>rm-dt-agr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>rm-dt-agr</name>
</project>
```

**Verification**

```
$ diff dat/file.xml dat/new.xml
8c8
<     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
---
>     <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I tried to run it on the other file (a little bit different ) and the script doesn't work:   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mmr.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>mmr-aggregator</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <name>mmr-aggregator</name>
 <modules>
  <module>mmr-repo</module>
 </modules> 
</project>

Comment: Hmm.. Can you edit your answer and post that snippet so I can see the format and indention? Looking, I see `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`, as long as you have that on its own line, there should be no problem. What does your `ofile` new datafile show? Any errors? If you didn't provide a second name on the command line for the output file, then look in the default location in the directory you ran the script from under the default name `newxml.xml`. Let me know.

Comment: The reason I ask for a bit more clarification, I just copied/pasted the script above and ran it against your sample data to test -- and it worked fine: `<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>` What version of bash are you running and on what Linux distribution?